# How to colour every sub group of points?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a set of points in r by "plot" command, I would like to sub group them by colour. E.x. I have 9 points the first three points in to red, the next three points into blue , ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to provide a vector of the respective colors

```
plot(1:9, 1:9, col = c(rep("black", 3), rep("blue", 3), rep("red", 3)))
```

Altough under normal circumstances you shouldn't do this manually, creating the vector of colours according to a grouping variable instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if possible for you to describe the second solution for the normal circumstances also?

Comment: well @RozitaAkrami, you would have to describe your problem in more detail first and give a sample of your data

Answer (score 0):

Without more detailed requirements, sample code and some example data it'll be difficult to determine exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps the `col` parameter for `qplot` is what you need.

```
# load required library.
require(ggplot2)

# create some data.frame with numbers and colours.
p <- data.frame(x=1:9, y=1:9, c=rep(c("red","blue","green"), each=3))

# plot.
qplot(x, y, col=c, data=p)
```

Hope that helps.